# How can I add some logic in my angular routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to lock some routes in 'case' sections for dependence of $scope variables (of valid or not-valid forms)

```
var loginForm = angular.module('loginForm',[
  'ngRoute',
  'stepsControllers'
  ]);

loginForm.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {



    this.returnUrl = function(tempN) {

      switch(tempN) {
        case 1:
          return 'partials/step1.html';
          break;
        case 2:
          return 'partials/step2.html';
          break;
        case 3:
          return 'partials/step3.html';
          break;
        case 4:
          return 'partials/step4.html';
          break;
      }
    };

    $routeProvider.
      when('/step1', {
        templateUrl: this.returnUrl(1),
        controller: 'step1Ctrl'
      }).
      when('/step2', {
        templateUrl: this.returnUrl(2),
        controller: 'step2Ctrl'
      }).
      when('/step3', {
        templateUrl: this.returnUrl(3),
        controller: 'step3Ctrl'
      }).
      when('/step4', {
        templateUrl: this.returnUrl(4),
        controller: 'step4Ctrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  }
]);
```

I believe that we need to add some service and then later it needs to be added it to config of my controller. But I don't understand DI things and don't understand how to write code to release it?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest **[$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)** to organize your urls

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
        $routeProvider.when('/step/:stepId', {
            templateUrl: 'resources/template/'+$routeParams.stepId+'.html',
            controller : 'step'+$routeParams.stepId+'Ctrl'
        });
    });
```

Comment: I need LOCK some routes from $scope variables. I need include $scope in my route-function, but in $routeParams there are not hints of $scope

Comment: what do you mean by LOCK ?

Comment: It's mean that some routes ('step2.html' for example) returned false or default case, if some variable from $scope was be false.